# Mirrored spreads page reshuffling: objects partially outside pages don't update positions

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, master-page

Working on a file with a mirror layout where the inside margins are bigger than the outside margins. When creating a new page in the middle of the file or changing page positions, objects are automatically adjusted relative to the margins **except when those objects extend beyond the document (trim) size**. (see image below)

Is there a way to avoid this. Working on a 400 page book where this pretty much happens in every page. I dread the moment when the edits require a page to be added or removed because I have to realign all the objects that are supposed to be cropped out of the pages.

I know I must not be the only one with this problem.

I've attached an example image.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Happens to everyone. Bleed items are relative to the pasteboard, not the document. It's annoying and I consider it a bug.

Comment: How are items configured? Are the color on master pages? Are they single page master pages or double-page  master pages? Customarily this happens when you use a single page master page and then shift from left and right.

Comment: This is a pretty basic file. The master pages are facing each other. The color is just to differentiate each object.

http://s10.postimage.org/mf03t7nnd/Screen_Shot_2012_12_12_at_2_05_15_AM.png

Comment: I wonder if there is a way (plug-in or preference) to change what objects relate to. To me makes absolutely no sense that an object that goes slightly off the trim area is not relative to the page.

Answer (score 2):

Skaught basically summed it up for you: Items on the page are positioned according to the page or spread; off the page you only get pasteboard positioning. Sad but true.

**The unpleasant solution** is to size down image/text/object frames so they are fully on the page. IIRC, the object can actually extend off the page to some extent but I'm not certain. It would take some experimenting.

**Scripting might help.** Way back in the CS1 days I worked on an on-going project with simple rectangular objects that extended off the page. I set up an AppleScript to temporarily resize them all and apply a script label with pertinent info. Then I shuffled my pages and ran an "unresizer" that read the script labels and put all the objects back the way they were. If you have the time and experience, you might be able to set-up something similar or ask the guys on [the Adobe forum](http://forums.adobe.com/community/indesign/indesign_scripting) if they know of such a solution.

Comment: Can you confirm the "allowance" you refer to? perhaps this is defined by or related to the document's bleed property?

Comment: Bleed or slug may come into play. I can't recall my past test (it's been a good long while). I would simply set up a test page and play with it.